# Why this route is working in express when not defined anywhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, express-router

I'm new to express and stuck in a problem while following some tutorial.
The problem is why this URL http://localhost:8000/user/profile is working? I haven't defined any route for /user/profile. If possible a deep explanation on this. How is this middleware working?
`router.use("/user", require("./users"));`

This is main file (index.js)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const path = require("path");

    const port = 8000;
    const app = express();

    app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));

    app.listen(port, function(err) {
            console.log("Server started sucessfully at port", port);   
    });
```

This is routes file in different folder (index.js)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();

    router.use("/user", require("./users"));
    router.get("/", function(req, res) {
        return res.end("<h1>Express is ready</h1>")
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

This is user file (user.js)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
        res.end("<h1>User Controller</h1>");
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What url would you expect the user file GET /profile route to match?

Comment: localhost:8000/profile, I expect this to match. By the way, way you deleted your answer? I actually liked it than the other answers.

Comment: I thought my answer was a bit redundant, but I've put it back up if that is of any help.  `localhost:8000/profile` would match the catch-all route handler - but not the middleware that is mounted at `/test`.

Answer (score 2):

In the main file you have defined this

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
```

it means express will use or any request that comes with  **'/'**  - will be redirected to route defined on  route/index page

```
router.use("/user", require("./users"));
```

Similarly , in your route file you have defined **/user** -  so any request that will come like /user , /user/xyz , /user/25 , (GET ,Post, put ,delete) will be handled/redirected to this user route.

and finally  in your user file - (all /user request will come to this)

```
 router.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
        res.end("<h1>User Controller</h1>");
    });
```

You have written logic to handle /profile page.

So if you links all the steps - it's will be from root  -`> /  -> /user -> /profile`

Answer (score 2):

Ok let's go from top to down. In your main index.js file you have this line

`app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));`
What this does is every request coming to `/` endpoint is handled by `./routes/index` file which you have given as a middleware

Now in routes index file you have similar function with /user endpoint
`router.use("/user", require("./users"));`. Now every request coming to /user is  handled by user.js file and there you have

```
router.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
        res.end("<h1>User Controller</h1>");
});
```

so now your endpoint becomes `/user/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what was already said, when `app.use()` matches an incoming request url to the path at which it is mounted, it actually rewrites the url by removing the part of the path that matches.

You can see that with the following program:

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.use("/test", (req, _, next) => {
    console.log("original url path: " + req.originalUrl)
    console.log("current url path: " + req.url)
    next()
})

app.use("*", (_, res) => res.sendStatus(204))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server listening."))

// console output when navigating to http://localhost:3000/test/whatever
original url path: /test/whatever
current url path:  /whatever       // the /test prefix was removed here.
```

If you pass a `Router` instance as a second argument to `app.use()`, the router will try to find matches for its own routes based on the current - rewritten - url.

Comment: What does `*` mean in 2nd middleware at path?

Comment: This is just a catch-all path, so the above will work with whatever path you use after the /test prefix.